# How to send different emails for each individuals using django backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, sendinblue

I have a problem arises while sending emails to users my system takes too long for sending each different emails to users

if single mail to multiple users is fine, but different mail to each user is time consuming

I'm Using Sendinblue transactional email for sending email  https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail

Comment: Are you trying to use a single send to compose different emails to different users? That's not possible. It is possible to solve issue of server slowness...

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to post one request to an api which checks and format the messages and send to relevant customer one by one, but taking too much time if i have more data to format, right now im sending email inside looping

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Django Celery email` package. It's a Task manager system and it can help you send your emails faster and outside of the main thread.
You can read more here: https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-email/